# how to call object instance methods from places they weren't defined

Tags: python

I have a top level script that creates instances of objects and executes instance's methods. I am very confused as how I can execute fetcher's methods from within the alarm_handler file. Specifically, line '`status = fetcher.get_status`' below. Hopefully this makes sense as to what I'm asking. Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

```
***file: master***
import fetcher
import alarm_handler
fetcher = fetcher.Fetcher()
alarms = alarm_handler.AlarmHandler()
site_status = alarms.compare_status()

***file: fetcher***
class Fetcher(object):

    def fetch(self)
        fetch a bunch of internet data

    def get_status(self)
        fetch some other internet data

***file: alarm_handler***
from master import fetcher
class AlarmHandler(object):

    def compare_status (self)
        status = fetcher.get_status()
        status_comparison = status comparison stuff
        return status_comparison
```

Comment: In the `alarm_handler` file, is there a `from master import fetcher` line, or something like that?

Comment: I edited the code to show my imports as well. It seems like I am getting into some sort of "circular reference" trouble. Is this true?

Comment: @BrianLeach: Well, are you getting any errors?

Comment: @BrianLeach: You are indeed creating a circular import. Perhaps you need to pass in `fetcher` as an argument to `AlarmHandler.compare_status()` instead?

Comment: Just a comment about the terminology (and I don't mean to sound pretentious)- I assume you mean you make instances of classes, right?  Unless you're looking for static methods in Python although I don't think you are.  If that is the case, though, then add the @staticmethod decorator above a `def` line.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That is exactly what I needed to hear. This worked perfectly and is the elegant solution I was after. Elegant meaning I think I understand the flow of the program in this manner.

Comment: @SimonT: I think that is what I mean. I'm still new to this and the terminology baffles me at times. I do not yet understand what makes a method static or not. I definitely do not understand the concept of decorators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a circular import. Don't.

Perhaps you wanted to pass the `fetcher` instance to the `AlarmHandler.compare_status()` method instead?

```
import fetcher
import alarm_handler

fetcher = Fetcher()
alarms = AlarmHandler()
site_status = alarms.compare_status(fetcher)
```

or perhaps pass it in when you create the `AlarmHandler()` instance:

```
import fetcher
import alarm_handler

fetcher = Fetcher()
alarms = AlarmHandler(fetcher)
site_status = alarms.compare_status()
```